# Images automatically spacing?

Tags: html, css, image

Hopefully this should be short and sweet, I am making a website and i want two 40x40 images placed next to each other, the problem is that their seems to be a rogue margin or padding that is being applied to it. I have tried to remove it but with no luck.

Image:http://i.minus.com/jblfTtkLGRaE74.png

As you can see i have firebug open and it shows that there is no styles being applied to the images to cause the blank space inbetween the images to happen. Also the images are not childs of a div. and i have used a CSS Reset.

If you need anymore information please ask.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you please post example on jsfiddle.net

Comment: Look at it. Remove the newline (equals whitespace) and update. The gap is gone. Just what I thought.

Comment: Ah thank you! It works. If you post it as a answer i can close this. But one last thing, having this on one line makes my code look messy. Is their no way i can seperate them onto different lines?

Comment: @user1171731: You can either [add `float: left`](http://jsfiddle.net/J6pgL/2/), or you can [format the HTML slightly differently](http://jsfiddle.net/J6pgL/3/). It's the whitespace between your tags that matters.

Comment: @user1171731: Close the question by acceping thirtydot's answer, it is the best one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because images are inline elements. Options to remove the gap include adding `float: left` to your images or removing all whitespace between your images in the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using firefox and you're certain that all the space taking values have been zeroed then it's probably the font size of of the white space, remove any whitespace or spaces between the 2 images, you can also try setting the font-size of the parent element to 0.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting, without looking at any of the code / the reset that you claim to be using. Here is how I would quickly put two images right next to each other using CSS.

```
img {
float: left;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
border: 0;
}
```

Sometimes you have go back and dig through your code a little bit and do a little rewriting. Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a table and placing each image within?

The main borders on the page tend to be wierd but I've realised the table method tends to allow for more refinement. Best part is it wont show up on the page.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the CSS

```
word-spacing:-1em;
```

on the parent container to remove these spaces between images.